# Headers in POST in Grails 3 app are not being sent with rest of service

Tags: rest, tomcat, grails, grails-3.0

Using Grails 3.0.9, and grabbing the freshest REST API with this snippet in `gradle.build`:

```
compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:4.0.7.RELEASE', {
    ['commons-codec', 'grails-async', 'grails-core',
     'grails-plugin-converters', 'grails-web', 'groovy'].each {
        exclude module: it
    }
}
```

I am trying to make the following POST request:

```
def rest = new RestBuilder(headers:["X-LSS-Env":"devmo"], connectTimeout:10000, readTimeout:20000)
response = rest.post("http://..../..") {
    accept "application/json"
    contentType "application/json"
    json jsonBuilder
}
```

Now, the POST receiver gets the json okay, give back a response okay, but this is the problem: it receives the headers as an empty map or as `null`!

So, what is the correct way of passing header data to the POST receiver? This is needed because the environment key `X-LSS-Env` could have different values, which instructs the receiver to do further routing based on it. Same with the GET request of course.

*** UPDATE ***

The consumer of my POST requests is actually a Java application, running on `Apache Tomcat/8.0.26`. The is how the service looks on the other side:

```
private javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest hsr;
@POST
@Path("/na")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response postSomething(Ggfp ggfp ){
    try {
        Enumeration<String> hnames = hsr.getHeaderNames();
        int i = 0;
        while (hnames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String headerName = hnames.nextElement();

            System.out.println(++i+ " headerName: " + headerName);
            String val = hsr.getHeader(headerName);
            System.out.println("         val: " + val);
        }
        String hval = hsr.getHeader("X-LSS-Env");
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity("X-LSS-Env is " + hval).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Calling this service from Postman works, headers are identified. Calling it from the Grails app results into an empty map - like I am sending no headers!

Answer (score 0):

The `RestBuilder` constructor never liked the way I used (or abused) it. Here is a clean way of achieving what I set out to do, with tryCatch logic if a timeout transpires.

```
def makePostWsr(serviceUrl, jsonBuilder) {
  try {
     def rest = new RestBuilder(connectTimeout:connectTimeout, readTimeout:readTimeout)
     def response = rest.post("$wsUrl/$serviceUrl") {
        header 'X-LSS-Env', 'devmo'
        accept "application/json"
        contentType "application/json"
        json jsonBuilder
     }
     response
  } catch (Exception e) {
     println "== problem makePostWsr on $serviceUrl"
     null
  }
}
```