# Which Grails version is compatible for jdk-1.8.0_45?

Tags: grails, java-8

I want to migrate the grails application which is running on grails-2.3.2.
Application shold be run on jdk-1.8.0_45.

Can anyone suggest which grails version is more suitable?

OR

Which Grails version is compatible for jdk-1.8.0_45?

Comment: did you google it first ? there should be lots on same question 2.4+ for 1.8 jdk+

Comment: @Vahid Yes, I have google it but the answer is vary from article to article so I decide to put the question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: my google search returned as first result http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517916/does-grails-2-3-x-support-jdk-8 which clearly suggests 2.4. Anyhow grails relies on groovy. If you research what version of groovy runs jdk 8 you will see groovy 2.3. If you then bind grails with groovy 2.3 https://objectpartners.com/2015/05/14/list-of-groovy-versions-for-each-version-of-grails/ you will see it is 2.4. If I had a penny for each time this question was repeated

Comment: @Vahid I had tried to upgrade the grails-2.4, but it seems many deprecated plugin not work on 2.4. that's why I asked this question to community.

Comment: And at the community is supposed to be aware of the `many deprecated plugin` angle of the question ? I think my point here is that if you had looked at the most basic search results from google JDK1.8 and grails 2.4 would have been linked. You have raised a question in regards to 2.3.2 and jdk.1.8.45. I think you should close the question down and think about what the real question issue here is. Obviously if you want jdk8 support you will need to upgrade from 2.3.2. No amount of questions will change the support of JDK bound to released versions and what was available at the time

Comment: @Vahid I got my answer. I have upgraded my grails to 2.4.4

Comment: Why stop at 2.4.4? Your biggest hurdle will be upgrading from older things such as resources to assets. This relates to gsp images styles sheets. I think everyone here including me initially suggested 2.4+. So why stop at 2.4.4 you can run what's in 2.4.4 in  2.4.5 with minor upgrades. The biggest hurdle is changing from 2.3 to 2.4. If you can change ide and get used to 3 then why stop on 2 go 3.2. If you can't and are using ggts then get latest version of that working with 2.4.5 or 2.5.x.

Comment: @vahid You are right but I am using IntellinJ IDEA-12.1.7 and this is no longer use with grails-3.x and my customer is not going to bare cost of new Intellinj IDEA that's why I am not going to upgrade on grails-3.x

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have upgrade my grails version from 2.3.2 to 2.4.4 by using [this](http://docs.grails.org/2.4.3/guide/upgradingFrom23.html) article. If anyone need help on that please let me know.

Comment: Your answer is a good example of why links do not make good answers (they were probably exactly right at the time of posting but now point to a 404 page)

Answer (score 2):

First, your Grails 2.x can run on a Java 8 platform, no issues there. Also, if you would like to migrate your Grails 2.3 app to Grails 3, you need to perform a sequence of steps I outlined in an answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097334/grails-java-8-dev-mode-support/34121542#34121542). Basically, you have to create a Grails 3 project first, then migrate your views, services, controllers and domain classes one by one using the steps outlined in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to upgrade to 2.5.5.  Late last year, a Grails project I worked on was on 2.3.11 and we had to use a Java component for compatibility with other products in the suite.  The Java component was said to work with both Java 7 and 8, but we could not load the component in Java 7.  We upgraded to 2.5.2|3 (I don't recall which version it was at the time) and we were able to run things without a problem.

Comment: exactly, I am using 2.3.2 as of now but while upgrading jdk-1.7 to jdk-1.8 some of the component doesn't load so I decide to migrate the grails. But not sure which version of grails. I will give a try with 2.5.5. Thanks :)